# Change Appendix figures numbering

Tags: numbering, appendix

How can I change the figure numbering from Figure 4.2 to Figure A.2 for the Appendix? I dont want to give the chapter title a number, nor do I want the appendix number to show in the table of contents.
Thanks!

```
\documentclass{dissertation}

\begin{document}

\include{title/title}

\mainmatter
\include{Abstract/Abstract}
\include{Acknowledgements/Acknowledgements}
\tableofcontents
\thumbtrue
\include{Introduction/Introduction}
\include{Methods/Methods}
\include{Results/Results}
\include{Discussion/Discussion}
\printbibliography
\include{Appendix/Appendix}

%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
%\appendix

%% Turn off thumb indices for unnumbered chapters.
\thumbfalse

\end{document}
```

**The Appendix Document is as such:**

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\setheader{Appendix}

\section*{Appendix A}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{images/FIGURE1.png}
    \caption{Figure one.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Could you please add where you got `dissertation.cls` from?

Comment: It's the TU Delft Dissertation template;

\ProvidesClass{dissertation}[2013/07/08 v1.0 TU Delft dissertation class]

Comment: Sounds like https://www.tudelft.nl/en/tu-delft-corporate-design/downloads/ "LaTeX templates - Dissertation" i.e. https://d1rkab7tlqy5f1.cloudfront.net/Websections/TU%20Delft%20Huisstijl/dissertation-tudelft-latex-ff9d073.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [dissertation documentclass from here](https://www.tudelft.nl/en/tu-delft-corporate-design/downloads/) you can add the lines marked with `%<-----` into your appendix. This will change the numbering of the images in the appendix to A.1, A.2, ... but leaves teh numbering of the images befor teh appendix untouched.

```
\documentclass{dissertation}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure one.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}


\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\setheader{Appendix}
\setcounter{figure}{0}                       % <---------------
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}   % <---------------

\section*{Appendix A}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Figure one.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!